# How do I mount a react component when an element exists in the DOM

Tags: reactjs

I have an element 'outside' of React that exists on the DOM i.e React is not responsible for it appearing on screen and neither am I. It gets put onto the DOM and has no callback I can use to fire off an event that it has occurred.

I need to perform some logic in React when this appears on the DOM. Right now the only logical way I can think of is by polling with a `document.querySelector`, terrible I know.

Is there any 'React`ish way to do this?

Comment: Please add the basic HTML structure, and the relevant react code.